# NoneType for 'org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats' .result("A")

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying code-

```
from org.apache.pig.scripting import *
P= Pig.compile("""
load_job_data= LOAD 'ics_job_detail_analytics_2016' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
job_detail_out= LIMIT load_job_data 2;
store job_detail_out into '$job_detail' using PigStorage(',');
""")

for i in range(1): 
    params= {}
    job_detail= "job_detail_out"
    params["job_detail"]= job_detail 
    Pig.fs("rmr " +job_detail) 
    bound= P.bind(params)
    stats= bound.runSingle()
    print(type(stats))
    if not stats.isSuccessful():
        raise 'failed'
    print(type(stats.result("job_detail_out")))
    #itr= stats.result("job_detail_out").iterator()
    #while itr.hasNext():
    #    print(itr.next())
```

It always gives me 'NoneType' and hence I am not able to iterate through the output. Any help?
Below are the last few lines of the output-

```
2016-05-23 22:27:10,977 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
<type 'org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats'>
2016-05-23 22:27:10,985 [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Output alias isn't avalable for hdfs://psvlxihpnn1.informatica.com:8020/user/gcs_dev/job_detail_out
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: First check, what value are you getting from `stats.result("job_detail_out")`.

Comment: 'stats.result("job_detail_out")' output is None

Comment: So now you know why it is printing `NoneType`. It doesn't have what you are looking for.

Comment: Well thats no brainer.. I know it doesn't have the output.. I am looking for why it doesn't have the output..